# AWK return path for files with NF <= 2

Tags: bash, awk, xattr

I think I'm close here but I'm missing something stupid. I'm trying to make `awk` print out the filenames for files that are missing extended attributes or are missing an attribute value.

So a file will have something like:

```
 getfattr -d /path/to/file/testfile.1

 # file: /path/to/file/testfile.1
 user.test="1"
```

`awk` should return the filename if two conditions are met; if `user.test` is missing, or if `user.test` is null i.e `""`. It seems like the obvious way to do this is to simply check the `NF`. If the `NF` is 2 or less it means that we're missing one or the other and thus we can print the filename. This is what I have so far:

```
readarray -t PATHS_ARRAY < <(find /files/to/audit type -f)

attr="user.test"

printf -- '%s\0' "${PATHS_ARRAY[@]} |\
xargs -0 getfattr -P --absolute-names --name="$attr" |\
awk -v attr_="${attr}=" '
  BEGIN { FS="[ ,\"]+" }
  $0 ~ ( attr_ ) {
    if ( NF <= 2 ) {
      print fname
      next
    }
  } { fname = $0 }
'
```

We're separating on `"`, so for a "correctly" set extended attribute we should get

```
NF=
1           2 3
user.test=" 2 "
```

and a broken one will be

```
NF=
1           2 (or 0 because user.test does not exist)         
user.test=" "
```

Comment: If I'm reading that right, you have the `{ fname = $0 }` block *inside* the block with the `$0 ~ ( attr_ )` conditional. Shouldn't it be outside?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Just a typo, it's outside in my tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `attr` instead of `getfattr` to retrieve the attribute.  This utility will, by default, handle attributes in the `user` namespace. It is easier to pull out *only* the attribute's value too, so there's no need for parsing:

```bash
find /files/to/audit -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        attrval=$( attr -q -g test "$pathname" 2>/dev/null )
        if [ -z "$attrval" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

Or, shorter,

```bash
find /files/to/audit -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        [ -z "$( attr -q -g test "$pathname" 2>/dev/null )" ] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

These code snippets would call a short in-line script with batches of found regular files from in or under `/files/to/audit`.  The `sh -c` script loops over the current set of found pathnames to try to get the `user.test` attribute from each.  Any pathname that generates a missing or empty attribute value is printed.

On Debian-based Linux distributions, the `getfattr` and `attr` utilities are distributed in the same package (called [`attr`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/attr)).

---

Slightly fancier, with a parametrised attribute name and output that will indicate either missing or zero-length attribute values:

```bash
attr=test

find /files/to/audit -type f -exec sh -c '
    attr=$1; shift
    for pathname do
        if attrval=$( attr -q -g "$attr" "$pathname" 2>/dev/null )
        then
            if [ -z "$attrval" ]; then
                printf "Empty: %s\n" "$pathname"
            fi
        else
            printf "Missing: %s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh "$attr" {} +
```

Or, following [the DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```bash
attr=test

find /files/to/audit -type f -exec sh -c '
    attr=$1; shift
    for pathname do
        unset -v issue

        if attrval=$( attr -q -g "$attr" "$pathname" 2>/dev/null )
        then
            [ -z "$attrval" ] && issue=Empty
        else
            issue=Missing
        fi

        if [ -n "$issue" ]; then
            printf "%s: %s\n" "$issue" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh "$attr" {} +
```